# Discord Now Installing In Kali Linux (Dependency is not satisfiable: libappindicator1)

Tags: kali-linux

I am trying to install discord in Kali Linux. I've downloaded the latest .deb file from the discord website. I typed `gdebi discord-0.0.13.deb`.

I am getting this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Reading state information... Done
This package is uninstallable
Dependency is not satisfiable: libappindicator1
```

How do I solve this error?

Comment: A "dependency" is a package that should be installed before the current package can be installed or used.  Most distributions have package managers to handle that, but users of Kali can solve those problems without.

Comment: Ok so how do u solve this issue ?

Comment: By installing `libappindicator1`

Comment: Have you tried ```sudo apt install libappinidicator1``` ?

Answer (score 3):

You can install it using `snap`. This helped me a lot on my Kali Linux journey.

Below are the instructions on how to enable `snap` on Debian and install Discord.

1. Enable `snapd`:

   On Debian 9 (Stretch) and newer, `snap` can be installed directly from the command line:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   sudo apt install snapd
   sudo snap install core
   ```
2. Install Discord

   ```
   sudo snap install discord
   ```

Congratulations. You have successfully installed Discord.

You can read more about it [here](https://snapcraft.io/install/discord/debian).

Answer (score 2):

As of Jan 19 2021, the package libappindicator1 has been removed from Kali Linux: http://pkg.kali.org/pkg/libappindicator

I managed to install discord by downloading the .tar.gz version from https://discord.com/download and following the .tar.gz part of the guide here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-install-discord-on-ubuntu-and-other-linux-distributions/

After following the steps, I was able to run discord it by typing `./Discord` in a terminal.

Answer (score 0):

What helped me with installing `libappindicator1` on Debian and in Docker as well - is installing this package manually. Also, it depends on another one `libindicator7`.

```
curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/liba/libappindicator/libappindicator1_0.4.92-7_amd64.deb" --output libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && curl -p --insecure "http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libi/libindicator/libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb" --output libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && dpkg -i libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb \
    && rm libindicator7_0.5.0-4_amd64.deb \
    && rm libappindicator1_0.4.92-8_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.